# TFS checkout something similar to SVN checkout

Tags: java, tfs

I have to get the complete code of a project, like SVN checkout from TFS using the JAVA Sdk for TFS. What is the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can acces the API of TFS, but it's not the best way to do. If you want just get the to work and back to repository, a normal cycle of development, you can use the command line!

To get the entire workspace:

```
tf get
```

To commit/checkin edited code:

```
tf checkin /comment:"New version of API"
```

You found the help commands of the tool in: [Use Team Foundation version control commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx)

Comment: Look for Team Explorer Everywhere to get Eclipse, command line, and SDK access from Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse you have a TFS plugin available in Eclipse Marketplace. 
[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301122.aspx) has all details of installing that. The page has further links to details regarding checkout and many more.

Comment: I have to download through java code to a particular location by not using Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Nope. TFS is a Microsoft tool. I have heard people implementing this in C#. But not sure whether there is a possibility in Java.

Comment: There are full API's available in both .net and Java for TFS. If you google Team Explorer Everywhere 2013 you will find the eclipse plugin, command line tools, and SDK for running on Java.